# REST Endpoint to send File in Java

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, file-upload, multipartform-data

I'm trying to write a REST API *(java)* that can receive a file. My REST API looks as follows:

```
import com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition;
import com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataParam;

@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                           @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
    System.out.println("File Upload invoked");
    return Response.status(200).entity("File saved to " + UPLOAD_FOLDER).build();
}
```

The Client that tries to send the file to this endpoint is as follows:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);         
httppost.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);
builder.addPart("file", fileBody);                        
builder.setContentType(ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
httppost.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse responseFromUpload = httpclient.execute(httppost);

int statusCode = responseFromUpload.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

However, with this setup, I am **unable** to hit the REST endpoint. And the TomcatServer log says:

```
[500] Exception occurred : argument type mismatch
```

Then, I tried changing the REST API definition as follows:

```
public Response uploadFile(MultipartFormDataInput input) {}
```

With this setup I am actually able to reach the REST API with the following errors logged in the REST API side:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.router.HttpMethodInfo.invoke(HttpMethodInfo.java:132)
at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MSF4JMessageProcessor.dispatchMethod(MSF4JMessageProcessor.java:130)
at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MSF4JMessageProcessor.receive(MSF4JMessageProcessor.java:72)
at org.wso2.carbon.transport.http.netty.listener.WorkerPoolDispatchingSourceHandler.lambda$publishToWorkerPool$12(WorkerPoolDispatchingSourceHandler.java:125)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've been trying different setups from different sources on the web and still am not able to properly set it up.

Can I get some helping understanding the missing pieces in my setup and how to correct them to make this work??

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have figured out the issue. My REST-API endpoint is actually a MicroService and not a JAX-RS.

Hence, the unmarshalling of HTTP requests is not the same as with that which happen with JAX-RS based REST endpoints. I have used the [msf4j](https://github.com/wso2/msf4j) microservices framework to write my microservice and they have explained how to handle file upload in their [fileserver example](https://github.com/wso2/msf4j/tree/master/samples/fileserver).

When directly invoking the microservice endpoint I can send the file as a binary stream as shown in the **cURL** command for their sample:

```
curl -v -X POST --data-binary @/testPng.png http://localhost:8080/filename.png
```

Thanks